# Execute Code Block on Forced Exit?

Tags: powershell, exit

I'm writing a script that runs for a long duration that, among other things, accumulates an array of log entries that are saved to file at regular intervals (just not every time an entry is added). The problem I need to account for is what happens if the script is terminated mid-execution and some log files aren't saved.

Is there a way to tell Powershell to run a code block like `Add-Content -Path $LogLocation -Value $NewLogs` before it actually exits?

Answer (score 2):

[Use `finally`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally):

```
try {
    # do stuff
} finally {
    Add-Content -Path $LogLocation -Value $NewLogs
    # this gets executed if an exception is thrown, if the script is stopped, 
    # or if it exits normally; pretty much always
}
```